# Look at $_SESSION changing

Tags: php, session, hook

I'm using joomla with a jumi page. Joomla and my php code share the session in all of the pages but one no...

I need a Way in PHP to understand where the $_SESSION var will be changed....

Is there a way to add a 'hook' to this variable ?

Comment: Only if you replace `$_SESSION` by object implementing `ArrayAccess`. But you'll loose all common session functionality. So this could be useful only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there is no way to do this.

Thanks to all for replying.

I'm adding this reply just to set an accepted answer